What cartoon show am I thinking of?
I can't remember what this show is called! It has the following features:

American Television
Mid 2000s?
Possibly aired on Cartoon Network
Contained Japanese Anime styles and themes (esp. facial expressions), but was probably American-animated
Could probably be categorized as a comedy/teen-drama
Very colorful
The writing could be called "clever"
Main character is a girl who has a crush on a particular boy who wants nothing to do with her.
Also involves a ninja
Also involves an old man that has something to do with dumplings? Or food?

I'm pretty sure all these are accurate, but there's always the chance one of them isn't. Is this enough info, or is this way too generic to be of any use?
EDIT - More attributes

Super-jealous friend/rival character that would combust whenever she got mad.
Setting is very Oriental-Asian
Colors are very flat (minimal to no shading)
Characters' heads are very round.
Similar in visual style to Powerpuff Girls or Ni Hao, Kai-Lan 


Telling us what the story was about, even in broad strokes, would go miles towards improving your chances of this question getting answered correctly.

Welcome to Movies SE, I am glad you've provided lots of information but most of them seem too generic to many animes. Can you add anything specific about any characters?

Any luck in this list? http://www.tv.com/shows/category/kids/decade/2000s/ Inuyasha ?

@StannisBaratheon There was also a super-jealous friend/rival character that would combust whenever she got mad.

This could very well be Pucca. Similarities:

Started airing in 2006.
Main character is a girl who has a hopeless crush on a boy
Said boy (Garu) is a ninja in training
There's an older character called Uncle Dumpling
Colorful, Asian-style animation
The characters have large, round heads and look very much like the Powerpuff Girls.

Here's the intro:




YUP! That's the one! I was just about to answer it myself! Thank you!

Tenchi Muyo! involves several women who are interested in a guy. There involves an older man who is usually knowledgeable in martial arts, but often provides comic relief, likely through food. It appeared on Toonami around 2000. for some reason, I feel this would be the closest to what you described,however I would hardly consider the writing to be clever. https://youtu.be/GrKcTQ7lJwY
Totally Spies is colorful and slightly anime-inspired, with stories often dealing with dating guys in high school. Appeared on Cartoon Network in the mid 2000's. https://youtu.be/M5umJtEXjQA
Kim Possible is a possibility. Kim has relationship issues every now and then. A bit more clever, very few ninjas though. Aired on the Disney Channel in the mid-2000's. https://youtu.be/U3JUB1L82Kk

Welcome to Movies & TV. You might want to consider posting each of those possibilities as a separate answer to make them judgable, votable and acceptable individually.
